# SQL Converting Parent-Child Query to Hierarchy Format

Tags: sql-server, parent-child, hierarchical-data

I am using a recursive query to extract a Bill of Materials from a database (SQL Server v15).  The PST table contains too many columns to enumerate, but the columns of importance are utilized by this query. [PST_ParentItemID] is the parent item and [PST_CompItemID] is the component (or child) of that parent.

```
WITH BillOfMaterialsCTE AS (
SELECT PST_ParentItemID AS Parent, PST_CompItemID AS Child, 0 AS 
level
FROM dbo.PST WHERE PST_ParentItemID = '601-2120-002'

UNION ALL

SELECT b.PST_ParentItemID, b.PST_CompItemID, cte.level + 1
FROM dbo.PST b
INNER JOIN BillOfMaterialsCTE cte ON b.PST_ParentItemID = cte.Child
)
SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY level, Parent) id, Parent, 
Child, level
FROM BillOfMaterialsCTE
ORDER BY level, Parent
```

This returns data that looks like this:

| id | Parent | Child | level |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 601-2120-002 | 516-6110 | 0 |
| 2 | 601-2120-002 | 601-6303-005 | 0 |
| 3 | 516-6110 | D4836 | 1 |
| 4 | 516-6110 | 422047 | 1 |
| 5 | 601-6303-005 | D4850 | 1 |

I need SQL to format this data into the standard hierarchical format so that the child elements refer to their parent's id.  The data would output like this:

| id | Item | Parent ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 601-2120-002 | NULL |
| 2 | 516-6110 | 1 |
| 3 | 601-6303-005 | 1 |
| 4 | D4836 | 2 |
| 5 | 422047 | 2 |
| 6 | D4850 | 3 |

How would my query need to change to accomplish this?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: It looks like you're eschewing the existing IDs want to assign your own with `row_number()`. Which is okay as a means of rationalizing the data but be aware that those synthetic IDs will change as the underlying data in the table changes. That said, I'd take a look at the `dense_rank()` function instead. I think an `over (order by [Parent])` will work but without actual data to work with (to @YitzhakKhabinsky's point), it's hard to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know the exact structure of `PST` table but I created something like the script below just in case someone would like to offer another solution.

```sql
create table PST(PST_CompItemID varchar(100), PST_ParentItemID varchar(100))

insert into PST
values
('601-2120-002', null),
('516-6110','601-2120-002'),
('601-6303-005', '601-2120-002'),
('D4836', '516-6110'),
('422047', '516-6110'),
('D4850', '601-6303-005')
```

My variant looks like this:

```sql
with cte as(
            select PST_CompItemID, PST_ParentItemID, 0 AS [level] from PST
            where PST_CompItemID = '601-2120-002'
            union all
            select PST.PST_CompItemID, PST.PST_ParentItemID, cte.[level] + 1 from PST
            inner join cte on cte.PST_CompItemID = PST.PST_ParentItemID
), res as(
         select row_number() over(order by [level],PST_ParentItemID) as id, 
                PST_CompItemID, PST_ParentItemID
         from cte)
select itm.id, itm.PST_CompItemID as Item, prt.id as [Parent ID]
from res itm
left join res prt on itm.PST_ParentItemID = prt.PST_CompItemID
```

I have added one more CTE because it is not possible to insert `row_number()` into recursive CTE

[image]

Comment: This solution works perfectly for converting a table from a Parent/Child view to a hierarchical view.  Thank you, @Olesia Dudareva, for solving this problem.